# Locust docker container cannot find the locust file

Tags: locust

I try to run locustfile in locustio/locust docker image and it cannot find the locustfile, despite the locustfile exists in the locust directory.

```
~ docker run -p 8089:8089 -v $PWD:/locust locustio/locust locust -f /locust/locustfile.py
Could not find any locustfile! Ensure file ends in '.py' and see --help for available options.
```

(I'm reposting this question as my own, because the original poster deleted it immediately after getting an answer!)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the extra "locust" from your command, so that it becomes:

```
docker run ... locustio/locust -f /locust/locustfile.py
```